# Fetching columns from 2 different tables and group by 2 different columns

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT aSites,count(MessageId) from messages group by aSites
UNION
SELECT bSites,count(callId) from calls group by bSites
```

I want 2 columns as output, 1 for messages and other for calls and group it by aSites and bSites (aSites and BSites has some common names).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group all elements in the first column (not distinguishing between `aSites` and `bSites` you need to re-group the results. Try with:

```
SELECT a.sites, sum(a.count) FROM 
(
SELECT aSites as sites,count(MessageId) AS count FROM messages GROUP BY sites
UNION
SELECT bSites as sites,count(callId) AS count FROM calls GROUP BY sites
) a
GROUP BY a.sites
```

Comment: Thank you that did it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT aSites,bSites,sum(asitecount) asitecount,sum(bsitecount) bsitecount from
(
    SELECT aSites,null bSites,count(MessageId) asitecount,0 bsitecount from messages group by aSites
    UNION
    SELECT null aSites,bSites,0 asitecount,count(callId) bsitecount, from calls group by bSites
)Z
```

Try above code.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'aSitecount, sum(bSitecount) bSitecount from (     SELECT aSite' at line 1